# How would I get all errors from a form group in angular 2?

Tags: angular2-forms

If I build a form group like this:

```
    this.passWordForm = this._formBuilder.group({
        "previous_password": [this.changePassword.previous_password, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        "new_password": [this.changePassword.new_password, Validators.compose([Validators.required,PasswordValidator.validate])],
    });
```

How would I get all errors from the form group? What I've been doing is this:

```
<form role="form" [formGroup]="passWordForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="submitChangePassword()">
<input [(ngModel)]="changePassword.previous_password" formControlName="previous_password" name="previous_password" type="password" placeholder="Previous Password" class="form-control" required>
<input formControlName="new_password" [(ngModel)]="changePassword.new_password" name="new_password" type="password" placeholder="New Password" class="form-control" required>
<div *ngIf="passWordForm.invalid === true && passWordForm.controls['new_password'].errors">
    <div *ngFor="let line of passWordForm.controls['new_password'].errors.message" class="alert alert-danger">{{line}}</div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="passWordForm.invalid === true && passWordForm.controls['previous_password'].errors">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{passWordForm.controls['previous_password'].errors.message}}</div>
</div>
</form>
```

I was hoping that `passWordForm.errors` would return a concatenated list but it's always null, even when `passWordForm.invalid === true`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all validation errors from Angular 2 FormGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680321/get-all-validation-errors-from-angular-2-formgroup)

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I think is to know if the form is valid or not by doing passwordForm.valid and then iterate over the Controls object and find the errors of individual form element.

Comment: @smartmouse Sorry, I couldn't answer that.. I have the same question too. [link] (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10530) This link has some discussion around this issue.