# Get all validation errors from Angular 2 FormGroup

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

Given this code:

```js
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  email: ['', [Validators.required, EmailValidator.isValid]],
  hasAcceptedTerms: [false, Validators.pattern('true')]
});
```

How can I get all validation errors from `this.form`?

I'm writing unit tests and want to include the actual validation errors in the assert message.

Comment: Instead of Validators.pattern('true') you could/should use Validators.requiredTrue to enforce checkbox being checked.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

I met the same problem and for finding all validation errors and displaying them, I wrote this method:

```
getFormValidationErrors() {
  Object.keys(this.productForm.controls).forEach(key => {
    const controlErrors: ValidationErrors = this.productForm.get(key).errors;
    if (controlErrors != null) {
      Object.keys(controlErrors).forEach(keyError => {
       console.log('Key control: ' + key + ', keyError: ' + keyError + ', err value: ', controlErrors[keyError]);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Form name `productForm` should be changed to your form instance name.

It works in this way: we get all our controls from the form in format `{[p: string]: AbstractControl}` and iterate by each error key, to get details of error. It skips `null` error values.

It also can be changed for displaying validation errors on the template view, just replace `console.log(..)` to what you need.

Comment: How to extend the above method for FormArray in the same pattern?

Comment: Did you mean `' + controlErrors[keyErrors];` instead of `', controlErrors[keyErrors];`?

Comment: @ryanm no, there is different in printing like object, or like string value.

Comment: from where can I import `ValidationErrors` in angular 2?

Comment: `import { ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';`

Comment: Please note this does not work for nested FormGroups, I would suggest Mayur Dongre's method

Comment: how to display the error on the html ?

Answer (score 44):

This is solution with `FormGroup` inside supports ( **[like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45837475/2051938)** )

Tested on: Angular 4.3.6

**get-form-validation-errors.ts**

```
import { AbstractControl, FormGroup, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

export interface AllValidationErrors {
  control_name: string;
  error_name: string;
  error_value: any;
}

export interface FormGroupControls {
  [key: string]: AbstractControl;
}

export function getFormValidationErrors(controls: FormGroupControls): AllValidationErrors[] {
  let errors: AllValidationErrors[] = [];
  Object.keys(controls).forEach(key => {
    const control = controls[ key ];
    if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
      errors = errors.concat(getFormValidationErrors(control.controls));
    }
    const controlErrors: ValidationErrors = controls[ key ].errors;
    if (controlErrors !== null) {
      Object.keys(controlErrors).forEach(keyError => {
        errors.push({
          control_name: key,
          error_name: keyError,
          error_value: controlErrors[ keyError ]
        });
      });
    }
  });
  return errors;
}
```

**Using example**:

```
if (!this.formValid()) {
  const error: AllValidationErrors = getFormValidationErrors(this.regForm.controls).shift();
  if (error) {
    let text;
    switch (error.error_name) {
      case 'required': text = `${error.control_name} is required!`; break;
      case 'pattern': text = `${error.control_name} has wrong pattern!`; break;
      case 'email': text = `${error.control_name} has wrong email format!`; break;
      case 'minlength': text = `${error.control_name} has wrong length! Required length: ${error.error_value.requiredLength}`; break;
      case 'areEqual': text = `${error.control_name} must be equal!`; break;
      default: text = `${error.control_name}: ${error.error_name}: ${error.error_value}`;
    }
    this.error = text;
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: Angular 5 change -     const controlErrors: ValidationErrors = form.controls[key].errors;

Comment: Suggestion to check for truthy on `controlErrors` 
i.e. `if (controlErrors) {` as checking only for `null` will give an error if errors is `undefined`

Answer (score 17):

**Recursive way to retrieve all the errors from an Angular form**, after creating any kind of formulary structure there's no way to retrieve all the errors from the form. This is very useful for debugging purposes but also for plotting those errors.

**Tested for Angular 9**

```
getFormErrors(form: AbstractControl) {
    if (form instanceof FormControl) {
        // Return FormControl errors or null
        return form.errors ?? null;
    }
    if (form instanceof FormGroup) {
        const groupErrors = form.errors;
        // Form group can contain errors itself, in that case add'em
        const formErrors = groupErrors ? {groupErrors} : {};
        Object.keys(form.controls).forEach(key => {
            // Recursive call of the FormGroup fields
            const error = this.getFormErrors(form.get(key));
            if (error !== null) {
                // Only add error if not null
                formErrors[key] = error;
            }
        });
        // Return FormGroup errors or null
        return Object.keys(formErrors).length > 0 ? formErrors : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Angular 7 and made two modifications to your code: `form.errors ?? null` I had to remove the ?? for it to compile. More importantly, in the FormGroup check condition, I added `|| formParameter instanceof FormArray` which really opened up my application. Thanks!

Comment: What about FormArray?

Comment: @greg93 replace the second condition with `form instanceof FormGroup || form instanceof FormArray`

Answer (score 12):

This is another variant that collects the errors recursively and does not depend on any external library like `lodash` (ES6 only):

```js
function isFormGroup(control: AbstractControl): control is FormGroup {
  return !!(<FormGroup>control).controls;
}

function collectErrors(control: AbstractControl): any | null {
  if (isFormGroup(control)) {
    return Object.entries(control.controls)
      .reduce(
        (acc, [key, childControl]) => {
          const childErrors = collectErrors(childControl);
          if (childErrors) {
            acc = {...acc, [key]: childErrors};
          }
          return acc;
        },
        null
      );
  } else {
    return control.errors;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Or you can just use this library to get all errors, even from deep and dynamic forms.

```
npm i @naologic/forms
```

If you want to use the static function on your own forms

```js
import {NaoFormStatic} from '@naologic/forms';
...
const errorsFlat = NaoFormStatic.getAllErrorsFlat(fg); 
console.log(errorsFlat);
```

If you want to use `NaoFromGroup` you can import and use it

```js
import {NaoFormGroup, NaoFormControl, NaoValidators} from '@naologic/forms';
...
    this.naoFormGroup = new NaoFormGroup({
      firstName: new NaoFormControl('John'),
      lastName: new NaoFormControl('Doe'),
      ssn: new NaoFormControl('000 00 0000', NaoValidators.isSSN()),
    });

   const getFormErrors = this.naoFormGroup.getAllErrors();
   console.log(getFormErrors);
   // --> {first: {ok: false, isSSN: false, actualValue: "000 00 0000"}}
```

Read the [full documentation](https://naologic.github.io/alexandria/#/forms?id=getallerrors)

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [@MixerOID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46080244/1919749) response, here is my final solution as a component (maybe I create a library). I also support FormArray's:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormArray, FormGroup, ValidationErrors} from '@angular/forms';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';

interface AllValidationErrors {
  controlName: string;
  errorName: string;
  errorValue: any;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-errors',
  templateUrl: './form-errors.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-errors.component.scss']
})
export class FormErrorsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  @Input() formRef: ElementRef;
  @Input() messages: Array<any>;

  private errors: AllValidationErrors[];

  constructor(
    private translateService: TranslateService
  ) {
    this.errors = [];
    this.messages = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.errors = [];
      this.calculateErrors(this.form);
    });

    this.calculateErrors(this.form);
  }

  calculateErrors(form: FormGroup | FormArray) {
    Object.keys(form.controls).forEach(field => {
      const control = form.get(field);
      if (control instanceof FormGroup || control instanceof FormArray) {
        this.errors = this.errors.concat(this.calculateErrors(control));
        return;
      }

      const controlErrors: ValidationErrors = control.errors;
      if (controlErrors !== null) {
        Object.keys(controlErrors).forEach(keyError => {
          this.errors.push({
            controlName: field,
            errorName: keyError,
            errorValue: controlErrors[keyError]
          });
        });
      }
    });

    // This removes duplicates
    this.errors = this.errors.filter((error, index, self) => self.findIndex(t => {
      return t.controlName === error.controlName && t.errorName === error.errorName;
    }) === index);
    return this.errors;
  }

  getErrorMessage(error) {
    switch (error.errorName) {
      case 'required':
        return this.translateService.instant('mustFill') + ' ' + this.messages[error.controlName];
      default:
        return 'unknown error ' + error.errorName;
    }
  }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="formRef.submitted">
  <div *ngFor="let error of errors" class="text-danger">
    {{getErrorMessage(error)}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Usage:

```
<app-form-errors [form]="languageForm"
                 [formRef]="formRef"
                 [messages]="{language: 'Language'}">
</app-form-errors>
```

Answer (score 3):

For whom it might concern - I tweaked around with Andreas code in order to get all errors code in a flat object for easier logging errors that might appear.

Please consider:

```
export function collectErrors(control: AbstractControl): any | null {
  let errors = {};
  let recursiveFunc = (control: AbstractControl) => {
    if (isFormGroup(control)) {
      return Object.entries(control.controls).reduce(
        (acc, [key, childControl]) => {
          const childErrors = recursiveFunc(childControl);
          if (childErrors) {
            if (!isFormGroup(childControl)) {
              errors = { ...errors, [key]: childErrors };
            }
            acc = { ...acc, [key]: childErrors };
          }
          return acc;
        },
        null
      );
    } else {
      return control.errors;
    }
  };
  recursiveFunc(control);
  return errors;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This , it will call validation for all control in form :

```
validateAllFormControl(formGroup: FormGroup) {         
  Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {  
    const control = formGroup.get(field);             
    if (control instanceof FormControl) {             
      control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
    } else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {        
      this.validateAllFormControl(control);            
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have got a requirement to present all errors of very complex FormGroup control which contains FormControls, FromGroups and FormArrays

i tried to fimd simple solution but I was not able to find the perfect solution which support all types of controls so i have develop the following simple recursive function and I am sharring with all:

```
export interface FieldError {
    formGroupName: string;
    fieldName: string;
    errorCode: string;
}

export function getFormErrors(
     control: AbstractControl, 
     formGroupName: string, 
     fieldName: string, 
     errors: FieldError[]) {

     if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
         Object.keys(control.controls).forEach(controlName => {
             let formControl = control.get(controlName);
             if (formControl) {
                 let fGroupName = formGroupName + "-" + controlName;
                 getFormErrors(formControl, fGroupName, controlName, errors);
             }
         })
     }

     if (control instanceof FormArray) {
         control.controls.forEach((fControl: AbstractControl, index) => {
             let fGroupName = formGroupName + "-" + index;
             getFormErrors(fControl, fGroupName, "Array", errors);
         })
     }

     if (control instanceof FormControl) {
         const controlErrors: ValidationErrors | null = control.errors;
         if (controlErrors) {
             Object.keys(controlErrors).forEach(errorCode => {
                 errors.push({
                     formGroupName: formGroupName,
                     fieldName: fieldName,
                     errorCode: errorCode
                 })
             });
         }
     }
 }
```

the usage is as follow:

```
    let errors: FieldError[] = []
    getFormErrors(YOUR_FORM_GROUP, "root", "", errors);
```

Answer (score 2):

Adapting [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44280487/2452770) to return a string that can then be printed to console:

```
function getFormValidationErrors(form: FormGroup): string {
    return Object.keys(form.controls)
        .map((control) => {
            const controlErrors = form.get(control).errors;
            if (!controlErrors) {
                return [];
            }
            const controlErrorsString = Object.keys(controlErrors)
                .flatMap(
                    (keyError) => `${keyError}: ${controlErrors[keyError]}`
                )
                .join(', ');
            return `${control}: {${controlErrorsString}}`;
        })
        .filter((list) => list.length > 0)
        .join('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over this.form.errors property.

Comment: I guess that ```this.form.errors``` returns only errors of validation for the ```this.form```, not for ```this.form.controls```. You can validate FormGroups and its children (arbitrary number of FormGroups, FormControls and FormArrays) separately. To fetch all the errors, I think you need to ask them recursively.

Answer (score 1):

```
export class GenericValidator {
    constructor(private validationMessages: { [key: string]: { [key: string]: string } }) {
    }

processMessages(container: FormGroup): { [key: string]: string } {
    const messages = {};
    for (const controlKey in container.controls) {
        if (container.controls.hasOwnProperty(controlKey)) {
            const c = container.controls[controlKey];
            if (c instanceof FormGroup) {
                const childMessages = this.processMessages(c);
                // handling formGroup errors messages
                const formGroupErrors = {};
                if (this.validationMessages[controlKey]) {
                    formGroupErrors[controlKey] = '';
                    if (c.errors) {
                        Object.keys(c.errors).map((messageKey) => {
                            if (this.validationMessages[controlKey][messageKey]) {
                                formGroupErrors[controlKey] += this.validationMessages[controlKey][messageKey] + ' ';
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
                Object.assign(messages, childMessages, formGroupErrors);
            } else {
                // handling control fields errors messages
                if (this.validationMessages[controlKey]) {
                    messages[controlKey] = '';
                    if ((c.dirty || c.touched) && c.errors) {
                        Object.keys(c.errors).map((messageKey) => {
                            if (this.validationMessages[controlKey][messageKey]) {
                                messages[controlKey] += this.validationMessages[controlKey][messageKey] + ' ';
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return messages;
}
}
```

I took it from [Deborahk](https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms) and modified it a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
// IF not populated correctly - you could get aggregated FormGroup errors object
let getErrors = (formGroup: FormGroup, errors: any = {}) {
  Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(field => {
    const control = formGroup.get(field);
    if (control instanceof FormControl) {
      errors[field] = control.errors;
    } else if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
      errors[field] = this.getErrors(control);
    }
  });
  return errors;
}

// Calling it:
let formErrors = getErrors(this.form);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a large FormGroup tree, you can use lodash to clean up the tree and get a tree of just the controls with errors. This is done by recurring through child controls (e.g. using `allErrors(formGroup)`), and pruning any fully-valid sub groups of controls:

```
private isFormGroup(control: AbstractControl): control is FormGroup {
  return !!(<FormGroup>control).controls;
}

// Returns a tree of any errors in control and children of control
allErrors(control: AbstractControl): any {
  if (this.isFormGroup(control)) {
    const childErrors = _.mapValues(control.controls, (childControl) => {
      return this.allErrors(childControl);
    });

    const pruned = _.omitBy(childErrors, _.isEmpty);
    return _.isEmpty(pruned) ? null : pruned;
  } else {
    return control.errors;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**I met the same problem and for finding all validation errors and 
displaying only first error, I wrote next method:**

> first declare variable on top
  public errors: any = [];
  public fieldError: any = '';

> now subscribe form on noOnInit 
  
  this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
  this.showOnlyFirstError(this.form);
  this.errors = []
  });
  this.showOnlyFirstError(this.form);

> now call function

 showOnlyFirstError(form) {
 Object.keys(form.controls).forEach(key => {

 const controlErrors: ValidationErrors = form.get(key).errors;
 if (controlErrors != null) {
      Object.keys(controlErrors).forEach(keyError => {
        const showMessage = key + " is " + keyError
        this.errors.push(showMessage)
        this.fieldError = this.errors[0]
      });
     }
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using inspiration from [Arnautg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7773940/arnautg)'s answer, I came up with this solution that will recursively combine all of the errors in the provided `AbstractControl` into a single `ValidationErrors` object.

```
function getFormErrors(form: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
  if (form instanceof FormControl) {
    return form.errors;
  }
  else if (form instanceof FormGroup || form instanceof FormArray) {
    let controlErrors: ValidationErrors = {};
    for (const control of Object.values(form.controls)) {
      controlErrors = {
        ...controlErrors,
        ...getFormErrors(control)  // Recursive call of the FormGroup fields
      };
    }
    // Return errors or null
    const errors: ValidationErrors = {
      ...form.errors,   // Form group/array can contain errors itself, in that case add them
      ...controlErrors,
    }
    return Object.keys(errors).length > 0 ? errors : null;
  }
  else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for case you want to also show all particular error controls in form. Simply call this function to check for untouched errors before save the form:

```
checkErrors(): number {
  let hasError = 0;
  Object.keys(this.formGroup.controls).forEach(key => {
    const ctrlItem = this.formGroup.get(key);
    const controlErrors: ValidationErrors | null = ctrlItem ? ctrlItem.errors : null;

    if (controlErrors != null) {
      Object.keys(controlErrors).forEach(keyError => {
          hasError++;
      });
    }

    if (hasError) {
      this.formGroup.markAllAsTouched();
    }
  });
  return hasError;
}
```

Of course, you need to have a valid error snipped added in each control input

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Text input</mat-label>
    <input name="textInput" matInput formControlName="textInput">
    <mat-error *ngIf="FormGroup.controls.textInput.errors">TextInput cannot be empty</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

If any errors have been found, a error message is also displayed for each element of the form have an error.

Answer (score -4):

I am using angular 5 and you can simply check the status property of your form using FormGroup e.g.

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, validateName]),
      lastName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, validateName]),
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, validateEmail]),
      dob: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, validateDate])
    });
```

this.form.status would be "INVALID" unless all the fields pass all the validation rules.

The best part is that it detects changes in real-time.

Comment: yes but we need to get the errors of an entire formgroup, not just know if its not valid

Comment: The OP needs the validation messages, which are not included in the status property, as it is just a boolean.