# Angular 2 forms - get form errors

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a form group:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  name: [null, Validators.required],
  email: [null, Validators.required],
  ...
})
```

How can I extract **all** the **form** errors and not one by one with `control.error`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680321/get-all-validation-errors-from-angular-2-formgroup