# Angular: what does myForm.errors stand for?

Tags: forms, angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I would like to get all errors from a form.
I tried to use the live example that came with [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), and I modified it adding `required` to the first field:

```
createForm() {
    this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
        name: ['', Validators.required],
        secretLairs: this.fb.array([]),
        power: '',
        sidekick: ''
    });
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/6b1paWOlKtXnDn1VVCyP

As you can see, if you empty the `name` field it triggers the `required` validator and `control` related to name field has an errors object... but `errors` property of `myForm` object is still `null`. Why?

Shouldn't it contain an object with all errors that are triggered by validators of the children controls?
So what does `errors` property stand for?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to loop through the controls of the form and see if they contain errors one by one. And I think you can actually have validators on the group it self, the same way you would have validation on a single form control.

Comment: It should technically contain the errors of its siblings, but in my case it's not doing that either. I don't know if this is intended behavior or a bug, but if you simply want to achieve your goal of collecting all errors in the form you could check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680321/get-all-validation-errors-from-angular-2-formgroup) question out

Comment: I can confirm this is intended behavior, have a look at [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11530) issue