# Trigger method when button is disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a form in Angular 2 and this is the code associated with button that submits the form

```
 <button (mouseover)="showMesageValidation()" class="edm-button" type="submit" [disabled]="!f.valid">confirm</button>
```

I want to trigger a method that prints fields that are not properly validated, but I read that disabled elements do not fire events. 
I wonder how to list items that are not valid when mouseover the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an `*ngIf` with the same condition so that errors are only shown when there are some

```
<div *ngIf="!f.valid">
 <div *ngFor="let err of errors">{{err}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to get element that are not valid?

Comment: `f.errors` should give you the information (assuming that `f` is a reference to the form.

Comment: {{f.errors | json}}  => null and some inputs are invalid

Comment: Hard to tell with the provided information. In the examples they reference the input fields individually https://angular.io/guide/form-validation, but I'm quite sure the form provides the errors as well (not doing much with forms)

Comment: Thanks for the help and attention

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong, `form` provides only errors for validation at form level. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45951372/217408 I assume the answer referring to DeboraK's is the right one, she's the Angular forms specialist.

Comment: Ok, Deborak's use reactive forms but I use template driven aprroach

Comment: It shouldn't make much difference. `f` should be equivalent to `container`.