# Angular 4 display all input validation errors

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validation

I'm starting to create my first Angular 4 app. I'm testing form validation. I created a template-driven form and I added some validators.

Now, I want to display validation errors for a field. This is my actual code :

```
<input id="name" name="name" class="form-control" required minlength="4" [(ngModel)]="name" #name="ngModel">

<div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
  <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
    Name is required.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">
    Name must be at least 4 characters long.
  </div>

</div>
```

I'm afraid to write this for every input in my form! Is it possible to write something like that (of course, I tried this code but it didn't work):

```
<div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
  <p *ngFor="let error on name.errors">{{error}}</p>
</div>
```

Thanx for your help :)

Comment: Have you tried the posted link answer?

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully this will help you.

[Simple Solution but not a generic one.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44280487/1343559)

It needs to be changed for displaying Validation errors.