# Angular: validation of nested form group doesn't work

Tags: angular

I implemented custom form control using ControlValueAccessor, which is introduced at Angular Connect 2017. slide is https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vTS20UdnMGqA3ecrv7ww_7CDKQM8VgdH2tbHl94aXgEsYQ2cyjq62ydU3e3ZF_BaQ64kMyQa0INe2oI/pub?slide=id.g293d7d2b9d_1_934 .
It almost works but validation doesn't work. What should I do to fix this?

I created sample app, so please check code from it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pub8qo?file=app%2Faddress-form.component.ts

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10530

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680321/get-all-validation-errors-from-angular-2-formgroup

Comment: thank you @yurzui! wow do I have to aggregate errors by myself? I thought there is a nice way because this implementation was introduced by Angular core team :(

Comment: I found this, "ANGULAR-SUPER-VALIDATOR" https://github.com/naologic/angular-super-validator