# How do I get validation errors from a form object in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I made a stackblitz with my issue I used templating to show the errors, when I do form.errors it returns null even though form.get('oldPassword').errors isn't returning null

**EDIT**
as a bonus I'm getting errors when I'm defining a getter for each field

```
get oldPassword() {
   return this.form.get('oldPassword')
}
```

**EDIT**

[Here is my code working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfgfe7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform%2Fform.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular doesn't expose control errors to FormGroup https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10530 But it does handle `invalid` state for FormGroup.

In order to recursively get all errors I would offer you using some function like:

```
export function collectErrors(control: any): any | null {
  if (control.controls) {
    return Object.entries(control.controls).reduce(
      (acc, [key, childControl]) => {
        const childErrors = collectErrors(childControl);
        if (childErrors) {
          acc = { [key]: childErrors, ...acc };
        }
        return acc;
      },
      null
    );
  } else {
    return control.errors;
  }
}
```

then you can use it as follows:

```
onClick() {
  console.log(collectErrors(this.form));
  console.log(this.form.get("oldPassword").errors);
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7vdflk?file=src/app/form/form.component.ts)**

Comment: Lots of great answers, however this one gave me the idea to use the invalid state to disable the submit button which is what I wanted to do orignally

Comment: way to complicated => `Angular doesn't expose control errors to FormGroup` of course it does

Comment: @Nickolaus then why is there an open issue that says it doesn't? At least not in an easy to access fashion. - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10530 What is your simpler solution to access all errors for all controls within a form?

Answer (score 2):

Check this feature request here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10530

The FormGroup errors object will be not null, only when a FormGroup validator returns an error and not for control validators.

Consider a scenario where both values are ok but their combination is not. That's where the FormGroup validator could return something like PasswordAndVerificationAreNotEqual.

Check [Get all validation errors from Angular 2 FormGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680321/get-all-validation-errors-from-angular-2-formgroup) to get all form group errors solution.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is the setTimeout in the validator:

```
    static passwordValidator(control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ==>    setTimeout(() => {
                if (control.value === "1234") {
                    resolve({ passwordValidator: true })
                }
                resolve(null)
            }, 2000);
        });


    }
```

`setTimeout` bypasses Angulars ChangeDetection, therefore the view is not informed about the validation error.

Therefore you should always use `Observables` in angular there is hardly a case where you need promises... and by using an observalbe you could delay the detection by `piping` the timeout and the form validation should work properly

**Update:**
Your password validator should look like this:

```
export class CustomValidators {
    static passwordValidator(control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
        return of(control.value)
          .pipe(
            debounceTime(2000),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            map(currentValue => currentValue === "1234" ? { passwordValidator: true } : null )
          )
    }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1su3cm

Comment: That makes sense however, I just removed the async validator and the form.errors is still returning null while the forms.get('oldPassword'). errors is returning an object, when they should be the same; why?

Comment: @RaphaelCastro  `*ngIf="form.get('oldPassword').errors && ..."` must be  `*ngIf="form.get('oldPassword').errors.length > 0 && ..."`

Answer (score 1):

for sure i am with nickolaus you should use `observables` it is much better if you cant refactor your app then use this

in html

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of getErrorList(form.controls)">
      <p>FormGroup errors: {{ obj | json }}</p>
    </div>
```

in ts

```
getErrorList(errorObject) {
  let errors = [] ;
  for(let key in errorObject){
    let obj={
      name:key,
      errors:errorObject[key].errors
    }
    errors.push(obj);
  }
  console.log(errors);
  return errors;
}
```

Comment: This is for a class, observables are later in the syllabus, we are learning the basics now. however good to know