# how to get the type of error of a Validator

Tags: angular, forms, validation, customvalidator, custom-errors

I have a simple input, I would like to get the type of error at submit.

```
  formGroup: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
     password: [
       '',
       [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), SpecialCharacters],
     ],
   });
```

For example:

```
   onSubmit(): void {
     if (this.formGroup.invalid) {
       //I get the type of error:
         //number of characters less than 8 
         //you have not entered any special characters
     } 
   }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all validation errors from Angular 2 FormGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680321/get-all-validation-errors-from-angular-2-formgroup)

Comment: Try to have a getter that returns abstract control for the formControlName and getter.errors should have all the validation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **"hasError()"** in order to specify what message you want to return for each respective error.

example for the password field:

```js
onSubmit(): void {
  if (this.formGroup.invalid) {
    if (this.formGroup.get('password').hasError('minlength')) {
      console.log('number of characters less than 8 ');
    }
    if (this.formGroup.get('password').hasError('SpecialCharacters')) {
      console.log('you have not entered any special characters');
    }
  }
}
```

Another option is to access formGroup control errors, example for the password field:

```js
onSubmit(): void {
  if (this.formGroup.invalid) {
    if (!!this.formGroup.controls.password.errors?.minlength) { // force it to return false if error not found
      console.log('number of characters less than 8 ');
    }
    if (!!this.formGroup.controls.password.errors?.SpecialCharacters)) {
      console.log('you have not entered any special characters');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it does not work in either of the 2 cases

Comment: I tested it on minimum length and it works, keep in mind that the error name must be identical. For exemple I wrote 'minLength' which is wrong. It have to be 'minlength'. For your custom 'spacialCharacters' custom validator, it have to be the error name that you are returning.

Comment: updated it to fix 'minlength'...
link to working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qh69zg?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

I'd try something like this for a specific formControl

```
get getPassword(): AbstractControl {
  return this.formGroup.get('password');
}
```

from the .html

```
<div *ngIf="getPassword.errors?.minLength">Minimum Length **</div>
<div *ngIf="getPassword.errors?.maxLength">Max Length ***</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I have solved it like this:

```
 onSubmit(): void {
     if (this.formGroup.valid) {
       alert('Password salvata correttamente');
       this.formGroup.reset();
     } else {
       if (this.formGroup.controls.password.errors.minlength) {
         alert('ERROR MINLENGTH');
       }
       if (this.formGroup.controls.password.errors.specialCharacters) {
         alert(
           'ERROR SPECIALCHARACTERS'
         );
       }
     }
   }
```

Is it okay?

Comment: Yes you can do that, even though for more comprehensive form errors I advise you to do something like Ramana suggested for displaying errors under each corresponding input and that way the user can correlate which error goes to which input.